# React with Node.js export two functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a JSX file like this:

```
var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
<Test>
...
var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
...

module.exports = Home;
```

But I cant manage that both functions load, I guess I have to add Test to module.exports, but I couldn't find a method that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `require("home.jsx")` it will automaticaly load and render your `Test` component inside `Home`.

It would be better to separate those components in defferent files, that will help you to manage components when your app will be too large.

***test.jsx***

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Test</div>
  }
})
```

***home.jsx***

```
var Test = require('./test.jsx');

module.exports = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return <div>
        <Test>
      </div>
   }
})
```

Of course you are also able to do something like @Mukesh Sharma answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you.

```
var Home = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
<Test>
...
var Test = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
...

module.exports = {
  "Home": Home,
  "Test": Test
}
```